# changing dropdownlist source misses selected value

Tags: mvvm, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use kendo mvvm to solve the following:
I have 3 dropdown lists, and I need that the option selected in one dropdown doesn't appear in the other two. This for all 3 drop downs.
I did the following:

```
            var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            fruits: [
                {Text:'apple', Value:1},
                {Text:'orange', Value:2},
                {Text:'grapes', Value:3},
                {Text:'banana', Value:4},
                {Text:'mango', Value:5},
                {Text:'kiwi', Value:6}
            ],

            fruits1: function(){
                var self = this;
                var sf2 = self.get('selectedFruit2').Value;
                var sf3 = self.get('selectedFruit3').Value;

                var fruits = _.filter(self.fruits, function(e){
                    return e.Value !== sf2 && e.Value !== sf3;
                });

                return fruits;
            },
            selectedFruit1 : null,

            fruits2: function(){ 
                var self = this;
                var sf1 = self.get('selectedFruit1').Value;
                var sf3 = self.get('selectedFruit3').Value;

                var fruits = _.filter(self.fruits, function(e){
                    return e.Value !== sf1 && e.Value !== sf3;
                });

                return fruits;
            },
            selectedFruit2 : null,

            fruits3: function(){  
                var self = this;
                var sf1 = self.get('selectedFruit1').Value;
                var sf2 = self.get('selectedFruit2').Value;

                var fruits = _.filter(self.fruits, function(e){
                    return e.Value !== sf1 && e.Value !== sf2;
                });

                return fruits;                    
            },
            selectedFruit3 : null
        });

        viewModel.selectedFruit1 = viewModel.fruits[0];
        viewModel.selectedFruit2 = viewModel.fruits[1];
        viewModel.selectedFruit3 = viewModel.fruits[2];

        kendo.bind($("form"), viewModel);
```

Where the dropdown 1 uses the fruits1 as source, dropdown 2 uses fruits2 and dropdown 3 uses fruits3.

It works, but if you start to change options in the dropdowns somethings the displayed value in one of the dropdowns changes without any reason.
For example, if I select "grapes" in the first dropdown, and then I start playing with the dropdown 2 (change it to mango, then apple, then mango and so on) the dropdown 1 display changes from "grapes" to something else (even though the value in the view model "selectedFruit1" is still "grapes").

I set up this jsbin http://jsbin.com/ebuhaq/1/edit where you can see the HTML.

So my question is:  Why does that happen? Is it a bug in kendo mvvm? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was some kind of bug in Kendo. With their new release (version v2012.3.1315) my code works as I expected.
(I was using the previous version: 2012.3.1114)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the drop down list is maintaining its selected index. So when the dropdowns are first populated, box 3 is set to grapes, which is index 0 in its list of fruits. When the dropdown 2 is changed, oranges now becomes index 0 in dropdown 3's list. In other words, I think it is always updating itself by the selctedIndex value, not the actual selected object.

That is just my guess though, I haven't looked through the source code to see if that is right or not.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the error, but I don't know how to fix it. supposedly, the dropdown should sync with the viewmodel property associated to the value